# Java getConstructor(types) with parametised types

Tags: java, generics, reflection

If I have a class with a constructor that takes a parametized generic type:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(Map<String, Object> data) {
      ...
    }
}
```

... how do I reference that parametized Map's class if I want to call:

```
Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(/*the Map class! */)
```

(Where `cls` is the Foo class.)

I want to do something like:

```
Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(Map<String,Object>.class);
```

... but that doesn't work.

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this!

Comment: Check out this link on Java ["type erasure"](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/java-generics-type-erasure/).  See also [Reflecting generic types](http://thekevindolan.com/2010/03/reflecting-generic-types/).

Comment: Ah yes type erasure, had I thought more about this and actually read what Eclipse was trying to tell me I probably would have figured that out! Anyway, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At runtime, this:

```
  Map<String,Object>
```

Is actually just a Map, without any parameters.

Calling

```
 cls.getConstructor(Map.class) will be enough
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reference the constructor by just the Map type.  The generic parameters are erased for runtime:

```
Constructor constructor = Foo.class.getConstructor(Map.class);
```